# python Or operator notworking

Tags: python

sorry im really new to python

im trying to keep the cursor within a 100x100 box but it doesnt do that, im still able to move it within a t shape spanning the whole screen and not a box in the middle of it.
it seems like its just ignoring 1 of the variables

what this is supposed to do is simply detect if the mouse has left the 100x100 area

the placeholder is simply so i can put somthing there later

```
pyautogui.moveTo(550,550)

while True:
    mos = pyautogui.position()
    print(mos[0],mos[1])
    if (500 < mos[0] < 600) or (500 < mos[1] < 600) :
        pass
    else:
        print('placeholder')
        print('f')
```

i've gotten this to work but im still confused why the first version doesnt work

```
pyautogui.moveTo(550,550)

while True:
    mos = pyautogui.position()
    print(mos[0],mos[1])
    if (500 < mos[0] < 600):
        pass
    else:
        print('placeholder')
        print('f')
    if (500 < mos[1] < 600):
        pass
    else:
        print('placeholder')
        print('f')
```

Comment: what do you mean is not working? what is not working? how is it not working? what do you expect it to happen?

Comment: Trace through the code line-by-line. In one case, you have two `print` statements, so a single loop iteration can only print at most twice. In the other case, you have four `print` statements. Can you think of some values for `mos` that would result in all four printing out in one iteration?

Comment: check out [pdb - The Python Debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) to debug small programs `python3 -m pdb myscript.py` .. use `b` to set a breakpoint (so you can inspect your program there), `c` to run up to that point (continue), and `?` to explore commands .. this will allow you to inspect the live state of your program wherever you breakpoint or continue to

Answer (score 0):

ok no clue but i fixed it by putting not infront of it

```
pyautogui.moveTo(550,550)

while True:
    mos = pyautogui.position()
    print(mos[0],mos[1])
    if not (500 < mos[0] < 600) or not(500 < mos[1] < 600):
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first version should have been

```
if (500 < mos[0] < 600) and (500 < mos[1] < 600) :
```

Because you want your cursor to be within the box limits both on the *x* and *y* axis.

Putting `not` in front of both conditions, and inverting the logic, as you did in the final version, gets the expected result because `not (not A or not B)` is logically the same as `A and B` (this is known as the [De Morgan law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws))

Answer (score 0):

I think this way is more readable rather than cramping everything into the if conditions.

You might want to consider adding a sleep to not overwork this process.

Lastly, the usage of "pass" serves no purpose here as it's meant to allow continuation of the loop. Whereas for your case you would want to restart the loop. Thus, we use "continue" instead.

```
import time
import pyautogui

pyautogui.moveTo(550,550)

while True:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    LeftRightPos = pyautogui.position()[0]
    TopDownPos = pyautogui.position()[1]
    if LeftRightPos<500 or LeftRightPos>600:
        print "LeftRight Out of Position"
        break
    elif TopDownPos<500 or TopDownPos>600:
        print "TopDown Out of Position"
        break
    else:
        continue
```